# Importing ElasticSearch Aggregation to Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

Within Elasticsearch docs I can see that they have a Moving Average Aggregation

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-movavg-aggregation.html

How can I import it into Kibana dashboard?